# Distributed browser test

Tags: testing, browser, cloud

I need to make a distributed browser test around the world. i.e i want to have x computers distributed around the world(not on the same location) all are running chrome beta (for now) and tell them to go to an address i decide for y amount of time and after that the test is over. i extract and analyze the data by myself from my servers.
I also need to know the b/w im getting on these computers.
There are many tools for stress tests .etc but they are usually running a lot of instances on the same machine.

Does anyone know of a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use proxies for this purpose. The load generator itself can be in one place but you can start separate load generators with proxies around the world.

That will achieve more-or-less a similar result (unless you want to measure client response times).

Since you're looking to extract data from servers, it should suit your purpose.